# formatted output of a number and field width, where does the C++ standard say about it?

Tags: c++

This code snippet:

```
//
// This is example code from Chapter 11.2.5 "Fields" of
// "Programming -- Principles and Practice Using C++" by Bjarne Stroustrup
//

#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << 123456                        // no field used
         <<'|'<< setw(4) << 123456 << '|' // 123456 doesn't fit in a 4 char field
         << setw(8) << 123456 << '|'      // set field width to 8
         << 123456 << "|\n";              // field sizes don't stick
}
```

produces this output:

```
123456|123456|  123456|123456|
```

The second print of `123456` is not truncated to fit in a field with width of 4 and Stroustrup explains that it is the right thing to do because a bad looking table with right numbers is better than a good looking table with wrong numbers.

where does the C++ standard say about this behaviour?

I found `ios_base::width` where the standard says:

> The minimum field width (number of characters) to generate on certain
>   output conversions

Is "minimum" the keyword here to explain the said behaviour?

Comment: Yes, *minimum field width* means that the field will be *at least* that big, but possibly bigger. It does not mean *exact field width*.

Answer (score 1):

The statement you cite is a generic description.  Regardless of what is
being output, the field will have at least that many characters; that is
the meaning of *minimum*.  The exact meaning of the field depends on the
type of data being output.  In the case of integer output, the exact
format is specified in §22.4.2.2; this includes not only how the width
field is interpreted, and a guarantee that the field will not be larger
unless necessary to display the value according to the format specified,
but also what character to use for the fill, and where to put it.
(Stroustrup's example leaves all of the other parameters with their
default values, but if you have a negative number, and specified a fill
character of '0', you wouldn't want it to result in `|000-1234|`, but
rather `|-0001234|`.)

For user defined types, it's entirely possible that the field contain
less than the minimum.  I would consider this a bug, but I imagine a lot
of user defined `<<` are written without consideration of any of the
formatting parameters.  The actual effect of `std::setw` is only to set
a field in the `std::basic_ios<char>` class; it's up to the
implementation of `<<` to handle it correctly.